# CSS animation fail on Chrome / Webkit browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm currently designing a blog, and I found a weird glitch on Chrome (and webkit browsers in general).

I put brackets around my "read more" link, that I want to move in a way on hover, and then go back on mouse out.
It works like a charm on IE or Firefox, but in Chromium, when the animation is over, it jumps back to initial position (I think it stops when the url pops on the screen).

```css
.read_more {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.read_more:hover {
  color: black;
}
.read_more:before {
  content: '[ ';
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:after {
  content: ' ]';
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(4px);
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(-4px);
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
```

```html
 <h2>This is an article</h2>
<p>
  Ut viverra vel eros ut laoreet. Pellentesque eu imperdiet eros, eu pharetra libero. Aenean id tempor arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [...]
</p>
<a class="read_more" href="#">Read more</a>
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Here is the codepen of my code : [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGNQxE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after). Inline elements aren't listed in the [CSS specs transformable elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) so they shouldn't animate at all.

This said, adding `display:inline-block;` to the pseudo elements solves your issues as inline-block elements are transformable :

```css
.read_more {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.read_more:hover {
  color: black;
}
.read_more:before {
  content: '[ ';
  display:inline-block;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:after {
  content: ' ]';
  display:inline-block;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(4px);
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
.read_more:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(-4px);
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is an article</h2>
<p>
  Ut viverra vel eros ut laoreet. Pellentesque eu imperdiet eros, eu pharetra libero. Aenean id tempor arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [...]
</p>
<a class="read_more" href="#">Read more</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the pseudo elements to `display: inline-block;`

Updated - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyvewX

Answer (score -1):

try to update your CSS codes to the following to avoid browser compatability issues:

```
.read_more {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.read_more:hover {
  color: black;
}

.read_more:before,
.read_more:after {
  content: "[";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}

.read_more:after {
  content: ' ]';
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}

.read_more:hover:before {
  left: -5px;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}

.read_more:hover:after {
  left: inherit;
  right: -5px;
  transition: all ease-out .35s;
}
```